# In France on one year visa. At year end, can I fly home from another Schengen zone country without being suspected of overstaying Schengen?

Tags: visas, schengen, 90-180-visa-rules

I have been in France for one year on a national French visa. I would like to visit the Netherlands at the end of the trip and fly home (to a non Schengen country) from there. Should I expect any problems? Will having receipts from France, to prove I had not been in the Netherlands longer than a couple days, be enough?

Comment: There is a point that the so-called duplicate question does not address: Do you plan to be in the Netherlands after the expiration date of your French visa?  If so, are you a citizen of a country whose citizens are exempt from the short-stay visa requirement?

Comment: Yes, I plan to be in the Netherlands after my national visa expires. I am from the US, so I have the schengen visa to stay in the Netherlands.